# tcpdf jQuery object conversion issue to pdf

Tags: tcpdf

I need to generate a PDF report and make that available as download on the screen.

I created an html to display the report and passing the html to TCPDF to convert the html to PDF.

There is a jQuery component in html which shows a graph. This graph is not converting into PDF.

If I display the html directly on browser the jQuery component runs and displays the visual graph but TCPDF is not able to display the graph in PDF.

Here is the jQuery component that I am using for displaying the graph: http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Minimalist-Graphical-Progress-Indicator-with-jQuery-Canvas-circleGraphic.html.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty naive to expect all the scripts, styles and dynamically generated canvases to readily work in any environment which is not a so-called «grade A» web browser.

TCPDF has its [graphic methods](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_012/) which you could use to draw vector images resembling your graphs.